# Determine dimensions of GIF image

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, webserver, images

How can I determine the image dimensions I need to use on my site at `http://orcacomputers.com`?  I want to ensure I get the correct image dimensions for a file named `patten.gif`.

I have an Apache error when the site loads:

```
AH00128: File does not exist: /var/www/orcacomputers.com/public_html/xry/images/patten.gif
```

I had this issue before and just named an image `pattern.gif` and loaded the page, but when I logged in, the image was huge and took over the screen for the user, so they could not see any of the menu options of the software.

Comment: The site loads correctly for me and does not give any 403 error.  The source code of the page has no references to the two files mentioned in the error log.  Also, where do you get the error you put as the post title?

Comment: `When I try to open the site on a browser on the self hosted local machine I get a 403 error.` What do you type into your browser as the URL.  If you are trying to self-host the same website and access it via `http://localhost` then this will fail because the virtual host is expecting it to be the domain `orcacomputers.com`.